# D3 - Update bar chart data onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I am trying to update my web page content when the user clicks on a button using D3. Unfortunately I can see that onclick new data is being displayed, but the old data is not forgotten although I use .exit(). My update code is below:

```
function updateData(param)
{
    // Get the data again
    d3.csv("bar-data2.csv", function(error, data) {
            data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.date = parseDate(d.date);
            d.value = +d.value;
        });
    alert(data.length);
    // Scale the range of the data again 
    x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

    // Select the section we want to apply our changes to
    var svg = d3.select("body").transition();

    d3.selectAll("bar")
    .data(data, function(d) { return(d); })
    .order()    
    .exit()
    .transition()
    //.delay(1000)
    .remove();

    // Make the changes
    svg.selectAll("bar")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("rect")
      .style("fill", "orange")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); }); 
});
```

Any suggestion would be much appreciated. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select the elements that actually exist and do that only once:

```
var sel = svg.selectAll("rect")
             .data(data);

sel.exit().remove();
sel.enter().append("rect")
// etc
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. I edited my question with all the code. I still cannot figure out where to add this.

Comment: In your current code, you're selecting "bar" elements. You never append these elements, so the selection will always be empty. And instead of `.selectAll("bar")` twice, you need it just once as in the code above.

Comment: Oh, yes, it's working. You were right indeed! :) Now my only problem left is how I also remove the text on top of bars.

Comment: Do the same thing with the text elements -- `svg.selectAll(".bartext")`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this tutoial helps: [Thinking with Joins](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/).

You need to update them, not just remove/add the difference between new/old data.

```
var bars = svg.selectAll('bar')
    .data(data);

// Remove
bars.exit().remove();
// Add
bars.enter().append('rect').style('fill', 'orange');

// Update 
bars.attr('x', function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .attr('width', x.rangeBand())
    .attr('y', function(d) { return y(d.value); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });
```