# How to update text in area chart when I change csv file on click in d3?

Tags: csv, text, d3.js, charts, area

I am beginner in D3. I made area chart which is updated when I change csv file by clickon. The problem is just text. Old text doesn't remove when come the new one.

Here is the code with update function:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" >
<title>Otroška imena</title>
<script src="D3/d3.js"></script>
<script src="D3/d3.layout.cloud.js"></script>

<!-- Style -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">

</head>
<body>
<div id="option">
    <input type="button"value="Adam"onclick="zamenjaj(value)" />
    <input type="button"value="Aljaž"onclick="zamenjaj(value)" />
    <input type="button"value="Sara"onclick="zamenjaj(value)" />
</div>

<!-- JavaScript -->
<script>
window.funkcija1 = function(x){zamenjaj(x.value);}

//Dimensions of canvas
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 40},
width = 700 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Set the ranges
var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom").tickFormat(d3.format("d"));
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left").ticks(5);

//Area
var area = d3.svg.area()
    .interpolate("monotone")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.leto); })
    .y0(height)
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.st); });

// Line
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
.interpolate("monotone")
.x(function(d) { return x(d.leto); })
.y(function(d) { return y(d.st); });


//SVG canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// y grid lines
function make_y_axis() {return d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left").ticks(5)}      

//**DATA**
d3.csv("Imena/Adam.csv",function(error, podatki) {
podatki.forEach(function(d) {d.st = +d.st;  });

// Compute the minimum and maximum
x.domain(d3.extent(podatki,function(d) { return d.leto; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(podatki, function(d) { return d.st; })]);

// Add the filled area
svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "area")
    .attr("d", area(podatki));

// Add the valueline path.
svg.append("path")      // Add the valueline path.
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", valueline(podatki));

// Draw the Y Grid lines
svg.append("g")         
    .attr("class", "grid")
    .call(make_y_axis().tickSize(-width, 0, 0).tickFormat(""))

// Add the X Axis
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

// Add the Y Axis
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Stevilo");

    podatki.splice(1,20);   

    var napis = svg.selectAll().data(podatki).enter().append("text")
    napis
        .text(function(d){return d["ime"]})
        .attr("class","graftext")
        .attr("y",50).attr("x",50);
});

// ** Update podatki section (Called from the onclick)
function zamenjaj(ime_s) {

    // Get the podatki again
    d3.csv("Imena/" + ime_s + ".csv",function(error, podatki) {
    podatki.forEach(function(d) {
        d.st = +d.st;});

    // Select the section we want to apply our changes to
    var svgUpdate = d3.select("body").transition();

    // Scale the range of the data again 
    y.domain([0, d3.max(podatki, function(d) { return d.st; })]);

    // Make the changes
    svgUpdate.select(".area")
        .duration(750)
        .attr("d", area(podatki));
    svgUpdate.select(".line")   // change the line
        .duration(750)
        .attr("d", valueline(podatki));
    svgUpdate.select(".y.axis") // change the y axis
        .duration(750)
        .call(yAxis);  

    podatki.splice(1,20);   

    var napisUpdate = svg.selectAll(".text").data(podatki);
    napisUpdate.exit().remove();
    napisUpdate.enter().append("text")
        .text(function(d){return d["ime"]})
        .attr("class","graftext")
        .attr("y",80).attr("x",50).duration(750);
    });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

These pages helped me: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23427274/why-does-d3-not-update-the-text) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869612/d3-update-bar-chart-data-onclick) but unfortunately it doesn't work for me. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Looks like it should work. Could you provide a complete example that demonstrates the problem please?

Comment: Why are you splicing out 20 items from your data before updating the text?

Comment: Lars, I added the rest of the code.

Comment: jshanley, I used splice beacuse I made such csv file, where is the element which is used for text written 21times, in each row. But I need it be written just once. Yes, it is stupid but I didn't find better solution. I don't know if it's possible to write element just in one row in csv file.

Comment: I believe that you need to clean up the d3 data object before appending new text. something like d3.select(element).selectAll(chldElements).data(newDataset)

Comment: Alex_B, how exactly can I use this? I thought that this already clean data: napisUpdate.exit().remove(); ?

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting the text elements using a class of `.text` but when you create the text elements in the `.enter()` selection you are giving them a class of `.graftext`. You need to use the same class for your new elements as you used to make your selection, otherwise when the data-join is computed, it will think you need all new elements, since the selection is empty.

Try it like this:

```
// selects all elements with class of `graftext` and joins the data
var napisUpdate = svg.selectAll(".graftext").data(podatki);
  // remove excess elements for which there is no data 
  napisUpdate.exit().remove();
  // create new elements for each excess datapoint
  napisUpdate.enter().append("text")
    .attr("class","graftext")
    .attr("y",80).attr("x",50).duration(750);
  });
  // update existing elements with the new information
  napisUpdate.text(function(d){return d["ime"]});
```

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't work. New text isn't shown and the old one is still here.

Comment: Also get rid of the extraneous `.duration()` calls. It doesn't make sense to call `.duration` on a selection without immediately preceding it with `.transition()` and it's probably throwing all kinds of errors for calling undefined as a function.

Comment: I resolved the problem. Your answer was useful too. Thanks! I would like to give you point for useful solution but I have't got enough reputation yet.

Answer (score 0):

After some hours I resolved the problem. I changed few things and it works:

```
svg.append('text')
    .data(podatki)
    .attr('x', 30)
    .attr('y', 50)
    .attr("class","graftext")
    .text(function(d) { return d.ime })
```

And in update function:

```
podatki.splice(1,20);   
var svgUpdate = d3.select(".graftext").data(podatki);   
svgUpdate.exit().remove();
svgUpdate.enter().append("text");
svgUpdate.text(function(d) { return d.ime });
```