# D3 - exit() and remove() not removing old data

Tags: d3.js

I try to achieve this: when files are selected, shown them in the selection dropdown.

Per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869612/d3-update-bar-chart-data-onclick), I created listAvailableCSV1(). However, it works only for the 1st selection operation. For rest selections, old data won't be replaces. My observation is that, once a position is ever used, it won't change. For examples:

Selection 1: FileA -> Display: FileA

Selection 2: FileB -> Display: FileA

or

Selection 1: FileA            -> Display: FileA

Selection 2: FileB and File C -> Display: FileA and File C

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="src/d3/d3.min.js"></script>
</head>


<body>

<input type="file" id="csvSelect" multiple>
<select id = "csvToAnalyze"></select>

<script>
    function listAvailableCSV1 (dropDown, csvFiles) {

        var options = dropDown.selectAll("option").data(csvFiles);
        options.exit().remove();
        options.enter().append("option").text(function(d) { return d; });

    }


    var csvSelect = document.getElementById("csvSelect");
    csvSelect.addEventListener('change', function(event) {  
        files = event.target.files;

        csvFiles = [];      
        for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            csvFiles.push(files[i].name);
        }

        listAvailableCSV(d3.select("#csvToAnalyze"), csvFiles);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I can achieve my goal with listAvailableCSV2(). But I don't understand what's wrong with listAvailableCSV1(). Why did exit().remove() fail to work? Is  listAvailableCSV2() a valid way for D3? Thanks!

```
function listAvailableCSV2 (dropDown, csvFiles) {

    dropDown.selectAll("option").remove();
    var options = dropDown.selectAll("option").data(csvFiles);
    options.enter().append("option").text(function(d) { return d; });       

}
```

I found another solution from the [document](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_merge) and this [discussion](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/issues/86).

```
function listAvailableCSV3 (dropDown, csvFiles) {
    var options = dropDown.selectAll("div").data(csvFiles);     
    options.enter().append("div").merge(options).text(function(d) { return d; });
    options.exit().remove();
}
```

The following questions is when we need to take extra actions to complete update + exit + enter.

Comment: listAvailableCSV1() seems to be suggested approach based on Mike's blog https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808221

Comment: You're missing the key function, like `data(csvFiles, function(d){ return d;})`.

Comment: It seems we need to add a function to update csvFiles. Would you please explain in which situation the function is required? Thanks

Comment: I cannot write a general explanation about the key function because that would be a duplicate. So, please create a **running** example of your code (using [blockbuilder](http://blockbuilder.org/) for instance), so I can write a proper answer specific to your problem.